# Filezilla - forced view expanding folders on remote process

Tags: file-transfer, filezilla

When running a remote process on Filezilla, such as deleting files/folders or changing permissions, it expands and shows each file and folder it recurses through as it processes them. This is a problem if it's recursing through dozens of folders and the UI keeps scrolling down as the folders open. When I scroll up to view other files/folders, it jumps down to the most recently opened folder by the current process. It essentially monopolizes the view of the remote files/folders. How do I prevent it from jumping down to the folders being opened or from showing the folders that it's processing in the first place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The FTP protocol doesn't support recursive functions like deleting directories with content. Filezilla has to

1. Get list of files and subdirectories.
2. Remove all files.
3. Repeat steps 1 & 2 for every subdirectory.
4. Remove the (now empty) directory.

Some FTP servers do support removing non-empty directories, but Filezilla doesn't even try to do this because it is not a documented function.